# Saving x and y cords as variables on mouse click

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, variables, save

I have a piece of code worked out that creates circles on a mouseDown function. I'm trying to save the x and y cords of the circles but cannot figure out a way around this. I need to save multiple instances of the cords from mouseDown.

Is it possible to do this in an array?

P.S I'm not looking for anyone to post code or anything. Just advice please. Or suggestions would be greatly appreciated :D I use AS3 and I am fairly new to it.

```
var posOne:Number;
//var posTwo:Number;
//var posThree:Number;
//var posFour:Number;
//var posFive:Number;



import flash.events.MouseEvent;





stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startDoodle);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopDoodle);

    function startDoodle(e:MouseEvent):void{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,makeTarget);
}




function stopDoodle(e:MouseEvent):void{

    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,makeTarget);

}





import flash.events.MouseEvent;


function makeTarget(e:MouseEvent):void {

var ellipse:Ellipse = new Ellipse (15,15, 0x00ff00);
addChild (ellipse);
ellipse.x = mouseX;
ellipse.y = mouseY;

//posOne == ellipse.x && ellipse.y


}
```

Comment: it depends on how you've your code setup so far, but an easy option is to generate a String that resembles your variable(s) and concatenate the values at runtime to it. Then it's up to you if you copy the 'code' from traces/ouput or use [setClipboard()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#setClipboard()) method to copy the string.

Comment: I have added the code I have so far. Thanks for the reply :D

Comment: posOne/Two/etc. are Number variables, so I presume you want to store just one position component(either x or y), but not both at the same time ? Also, is it safe to presume that since you want to save 5 values, you want the 5 most recent mouse positions ? If so, you should have an array to store values into and shift older values by 1 as you add a new value in the array.

Comment: Currently I'm trying to add a counter that counts the ammount mouse clicks, depending on the click number it will save the variables of mouseX and mouseY. I'm trying to save both at the same time actually, should they be int instead? I will try the array shortly, yes the five most recent clicks is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to approach this, would be to create `Point` objects with `x` and `y` coordinates of the Mouse click and push them to array.

```
function onMouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var mousePoint:Point = new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
    mouseClicks.push(mousePoint);
}
```

If you need to store loads of these types of coords, and you're worrying about performance or memory, you could save coordinate string representations with strings, in certain format, containing certain delimiters, like `85|56$104|77$...`, that way you will know, that every set of `x` and `y` values are delimited by one symbol, and the `x` and `y` values within the set are delimited by other delimiter. The best way to store this data memory wise, would be to limit your input to 16 bit integers and then store both values into 32 bit integer (`x` value into first 16 bits and `y` value to last 16 bits, for example) by using bitwise operations.

Comment: Probably scratch out saving values and concatenating them to strings — would actually take up more memory than `int` or `Number` values. You could just push `int` values into arrays, and `array.shift` two of them and treat the first as `x` and the second as `y`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is actually easier to see in code than to explain.  Not that you shouldn't read up on using the mouse points, but for an overview, the code below should give you a pretty good start on using points, given what you have above.  Please see the comments for details.

```
// It helps to keep all the imports at hte top of your file, for easy code reading.

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;

// It helps to keep all class-level variables at the top of the file.

// Make an array rather than many individual variables.  That way you can use a for-loop to access the items.
// (The brackets "[]" are equivalent to new Array().)
var localPosArray:Array = [];
var globalPosArray:Array = [];
var ellipseArr:Array = [];

// can use these as temporary variables:
var localPoint:Point;
var globalPoint:Point;

// stores currently active ellipse index:
var curEllipseIdx:int;

// stores currently active point index:
var curPtIdx:int;

// store click count:
// (You could use an array instead, but probably not necessary.)
var countTotal:int = 0;

// Probably not needed:
// var posOne:Number;
//var posTwo:Number;
//var posThree:Number;
//var posFour:Number;
//var posFive:Number;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDoodle);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, sizeDoodle);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDoodle);

function startDoodle(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
    // count clicks (mouse downs):
    countTotal++;

    // to find the coordinates on the local object -- this is usually different from the global coordinates.
    curPtIdx = localPosArray.length;
    localPosArray[curPtIdx] = new Point(ev.localX, ev.localY);

    // alternately, to overwrite a current point:
    //   curPtIdx = 0;
    //   localPosArray[curPtIdx] = new Point(ev.localX, ev.localY); // the old value will be garbage collected, if there are no other references.

    // to convert from local to global coordinates:
    //   curPtIdx = 0;
    //   globalPoint = localToGlobal(localPosArray[curPtIdx]);


    // alternately, to find the coordinates on the global object (the stage):
    curPtIdx = globalPosArray.length;
    globalPosArray[globalPosArray.length] = new Point(ev.stageX, ev.stageY);

    // alternately, to overwrite a current point:
    //   curPtIdx = 0;
    //   globalPosArray[curPtIdx] = new Point(ev.stageX, ev.stageY); // the old value will be garbage collected, if there are no other references.

    // to convert from local to global coordinates:
    //   curPtIdx = 0;
    //   localPoint = globalToLocal(globalPosArray[curPtIdx]);


    //You do not need to stop listening for mouse *down*, since that can never happen when the mouse is down. 
    // stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, makeTarget);
}

function stopDoodle(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //You do not need to stop listening for mouse *up*, since that can never happen when the mouse is up. 
    //stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, makeTarget);
}

function makeTarget(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    curPtIdx = 0;
    curEllipseIdx = ellipseArr.length;
    ellipseArr[curEllipseIdx] = new Ellipse(localPosArray[curPtIdx].x, localPosArray[curPtIdx].x, 0x00ff00);
    addChild(ellipseArr[curEllipseIdx]);

    // These lines are probably not necessary:
    //ellipse.x = mouseX;
    //ellipse.y = mouseY;

    // What is this for?
    //posOne == ellipse.x && ellipse.y
}

function sizeDoodle(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (ellipseArr && ellipseArr[curEllipseIdx])
    {
        // size the ellipse by the distance from the initial point:
        // however you might do that.
    }
}
```